# How to merge two dictionaries?

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm building a program powered by Spotify API with Spotipy library. I want to get a user's saved tracks in their Spotify library. Spotipy has a function called current_user_saved_tracks and does that exactly. But there's a track limit which is 50. I wanted to get 100 tracks so I used this function two times with different offsets (Offset indicates the starting point of getting tracks.).

```
results1 = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=50, offset=0, market=None)
```

and

```
results2 = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=50, offset=50, market=None)
```

Then I tried to merge these two dictionaries(?).

```
results = dict(list(results1.items()) + list(results2.items()))
```

But whenever I run my program and take a look at my sqlite database where track information stores, only the 2nd dictionary (results2) shows up for 2 times. I get 100 tracks indeed but, I get the second part 2 times.

I guess there's some kind of problem with my merging system. Help me if you know how to get that 100 distinct tracks.

**EDIT**

This one shows results2, 2 times (Basically nothing has changed.):

```
results = results1 | results2
```

This one shows results2, just once (The track amount is now 50.):

```
results = {**results1, **results2}
```

**FINAL EDIT**

I've tried all of your solutions but the problem remains unresolved. So I wrote the related for loops for results1 and results2 separately and it kind of worked (instead of 100 tracks, now I get 200 but I got that distinct 100 tracks). But thank you for your time!

Comment: I do not see how the SQLITE tag is relevant.

Comment: Please write a shorter question with the input (so minified, specific external data are not relevant for general Python question) and the expected output.

Comment: you can merge dicts with `d = e | f` since python 3.9, previously the command was `d = {**e, **f}`, unpacking and repacking.

Comment: The last edit does not make sense at all, the methods of merging a dictionary are equivalent, I believe you have an error later on

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to merge two dictionaries in Python:

```py
In [1]: numbers = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

In [2]: letters = {"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"}

In [3]: {**numbers, **letters}
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, '1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}

In [4]: numbers | letters
Out[4]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, '1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}

In [5]: # Above is Python 3.10+ only
```

If you have Python 3.10+, the second is preferred.

Comment: Considering that `dict(list(results1.items()) + list(results2.items()))` is also a valid way to merge two dictionaries why would changing the merging code help?

Comment: I'd argue it's more concise and probably more efficient. It looks more pythonic.